# Visual Studio 2012 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I just did a fresh install of windows 8 (+updates) and Visual Studio 2012, and when i run Visual Studio it gives me a compatibility issue and i can't find a way to fix it.

[image]

Comment: and what happens if you choose "Get help online"?

Comment: I haven't personally installed VS2012 on Windows 8, just Windows 7, but I did note that there is an explicit [VS2012 Express version for Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8).  Are you using Express?  If not, there is also VS2012 [Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188) (and soon [Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39067)) to apply.  Maybe that will fix the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen also raises a good point - what Edition are you using?

Comment: I am using the Ultimate edition. It seems that the Update 2 did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of this message, you need to install Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 or later, you can get it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39305
or through VS IDE -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates.