# Visual Studio 2012 & Windows 8: Program Incompatibility Assistant Warning

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

Upon every start-up of VS2012 in a freshly-installed Windows 8 computer, I get a series of Program Incompatibility Assistant warnings. I'd suppressed the majority of them, so can't get all the details of all the "modules," etc., that are warning as incompatible.

If someone knows where to tick / un-tick that option to restore all warnings, I'll be happy to give the full list.

The remaining image is the one I hadn't set to suppress, as a reminder that there's some compatibility issue right now. See example below:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259179/visual-studio-2012-compatibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install latest Update 4 for Visual studio 2012.

From Visual Studio menu Tools - Extensions & Updates; In the window click Updates & Install Update 4.

Rather than this You can use the fallowing link & install Update 4
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39305 ]

Comment: Haven't tested this solution yet (OTG ATM), but this sounds like an appropriate answer.